# Which one of the following sentences is correct?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

```
1) He did not came yet.
    OR
2) He did not come yet.
```

Are both sentences correct or only one of them and why?

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct.

If you mean that he did not come, but you expect him to come in the future, this would be correct:

> He has not come yet.

If you mean that he did not come (before a certain time in the past), but he might have come after that time, this would be correct:

> He had not come yet.

Comment: I agree, although the O.P.'s #2 might be used to mean your #1. It wouldn't be "proper" English, but I could see someone saying in on the phone or something (unlike the O.P.'s #1).